# Differentiability of a function at a point to prove it differentiable everywhere on the given condition.

Tags: calculus, functions

A simple question which I came across recently. Just wanted to confirm if my logic on it is right....

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function and it's given that it's differentiable everywhere except possibly at $0$, but for the point "$0$", it's given that $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x) = 0.$ We need to prove that its differentiable everywhere.

What I think is the left hand derivative will be equal to $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x) = 0$ and similarly right hand derivative will be equal to $0$ too on similar lines.

Is this right? I thought of the question myself as I was working on some other question and this bumped in my head. Can we do it this way or there should be some more condition given in the question to work our proof? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to prove the one-sided derivatives (the limit of the difference quotients) actually exist and equal $0$. Also, for your statement to be true, you need to assume that $f$ is continuous at $0$. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296283/lim-x-to-cfx-l-implies-fc-l) and [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373170/analysis-proof-mean-value-theorem) for ideas.

Comment: Consider the function that is $1$ at $0$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks David for the links... got the concept!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $0$. Without this assumption, user [math_man](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78871)'s answer shows that the statement is not true.

We need to argue that $\displaystyle f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h$ exists. But this is now immediate from [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule): The assumptions that $f$ is continuous at $0$ (and therefore everywhere), and differentiable away from $0$ give us that we can apply the mean-value theorem. This allows us to conclude that for any $h$ there is a $\xi_h$ in between $0$ and $h$ such that $$ \frac{f(h)-f(0)}h=\frac{f'(\xi_h)}1=f'(\xi_h). $$ Now note that $\xi_h\to0$ as $h\to 0$. Since we are given that $\lim_{t\to0}f'(t)=0$, it follows that $\lim_{h\to0}f'(\xi_h)=0$ as well, so $f'(0)$ exists and is $0$.

Comment: this cleared everything...thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Why does it follow that limit is equal to $0$? $f'$ needs not be continuous, so why $\xi_h\to0$ as $h\to0$ and $f'(t)\to0$ as $t\to0$ imply $f'(\xi(h))\to0$ as $h\to0$?

Comment: @sas This is immediate from the definition of limit.

Comment: Suppose $\xi(h)=0$ everywhere and $f'(t)=0$ everywhere except $f'(0)=1$ (I know that can'be true for derivative, but let it be arbitrary function). Then $\xi\to0$ as $h\to0$, $f'\to0$ as $t\to0$ but limit of $f'(\xi(h))$ is equal to $1$

Comment: @sas $\xi_h$ is not zero by definition.

Comment: I agree, but how exactly do you ensure the last sentence in your answer? It is not true for arbitrary functions, so you must use some propositions or properties of derivative, etc

Comment: @sas It is immediate from the definition of limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49054/discussion-between-sas-and-andres-e-caicedo).

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you imagine the function $f(x)=1 \;\;x\in [0,\infty)$ and $f(x)=-1\;\;x\in(-\infty,0)$ then it is differentiable everywhere except in $0$ and $f'(x)=0\;\forall x\neq 0$. Anda $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=0$. And this functions  is not continuous in $0$, and so it is not differentiable.

Comment: thanks for your feedback...got the visualization now...